# Error executing rnn model . How to fix it?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

Laptop specs : 
OS : Mac OS Mojave
Python : 3.7

while fitting a rnn model i get the following error :

> InvalidArgumentError: No OpKernel was registered to support Op 'CudnnRNN' >with these attrs.  Registered devices: [CPU], Registered kernels:

```
> [[node cu_dnnlstm/CudnnRNN (defined at <ipython-input-15->580eb6f63222>:3)  = CudnnRNN[T=DT_FLOAT, direction="unidirectional", >dropout=0, input_mode="linear_input", is_training=true, rnn_mode="lstm", >seed=0, seed2=0](cu_dnnlstm/transpose, cu_dnnlstm/ExpandDims, >cu_dnnlstm/ExpandDims_1, cu_dnnlstm/concat)]]
```

> Caused by op 'cu_dnnlstm/CudnnRNN', defined at:
>   File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/runpy.py", line 193, in >_run_module_as_main
>     "**main**", mod_spec)
>   File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
>    exec(code, run_globals)
>   File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/ipykernel_launcher.py", >line 16, in 
>     app.launch_new_instance()
>   File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site->packages/traitlets/config/application.py", line 658, in launch_instance
>     app.start()
>   File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/ipykernel/kernelapp.py", >line 497, in start
>     self.io_loop.start()
>   File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site->packages/tornado/platform/asyncio.py", line 132, in start
>     self.asyncio_loop.run_forever()
>   File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/asyncio/base_events.py", line 523, in >run_forever
>     self._run_once()
>   File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/asyncio/base_events.py", line 1758, in >_run_once
>     handle._run()
>   File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/asyncio/events.py", line 88, in _run
>   self._context.run(self._callback, *self._args)
>   File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tornado/ioloop.py", line >758, in _run_callback
>     ret = callback()
>   File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tornado/stack_context.py", >line 300, in null_wrapper
>     return fn(*args, **kwargs)
>   File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site->packages/zmq/eventloop/zmqstream.py", line 536, in 
>     self.io_loop.add_callback(lambda : self._handle_events(self.socket, 0))
>   File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site- >packages/zmq/eventloop/zmqstream.py", line 450, in _handle_events
>     self._handle_recv()
>   File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site->packages/zmq/eventloop/zmqstream.py", line 480, in _handle_recv
>     self._run_callback(callback, msg)
>   File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site->packages/zmq/eventloop/zmqstream.py", line 432, in _run_callback
>     callback(*args, **kwargs)
>   File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tornado/stack_context.py", 
>   line 300, in null_wrapper
>       return fn(*args, **kwargs)
>     File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/ipykernel/kernelbase.py", line 283, in dispatcher
>       return self.dispatch_shell(stream, msg)
>     File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/ipykernel/kernelbase.py", line 233, in dispatch_shell
>       handler(stream, idents, msg)
>     File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/ipykernel/kernelbase.py", line 399, in execute_request
>       user_expressions, allow_stdin)
>     File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/ipykernel/ipkernel.py", line 208, in do_execute
>       res = shell.run_cell(code, store_history=store_history, silent=silent)
>     File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/ipykernel/zmqshell.py", line 537, in run_cell
>       return super(ZMQInteractiveShell, self).run_cell(*args, **kwargs)
>     File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 2662, in run_cell
>       raw_cell, store_history, silent, shell_futures)
>     File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 2785, in _run_cell
>       interactivity=interactivity, compiler=compiler, result=result)
>     File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 2901, in run_ast_nodes
>       if self.run_code(code, result):
>     File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 2961, in run_code
>       exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
>     File "", line 3, in 
>       model.add(CuDNNLSTM(128,input_shape = (x_train.shape[1:]) ,return_sequences=True))
>     File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/training/checkpointable/base.py", line 474, in _method_wrapper
>       method(self, *args, **kwargs)
>     File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/sequential.py", line 159, in add
>       layer(x)
>     File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/layers/recurrent.py", line 619, in **call**
>       return super(RNN, self).**call**(inputs, **kwargs)
>     File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/base_layer.py", line 757, in **call**
>       outputs = self.call(inputs, *args, **kwargs)
>     File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/layers/cudnn_recurrent.py", line 109, in call
>       output, states = self._process_batch(inputs, initial_state)
>     File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/layers/cudnn_recurrent.py", line 493, in _process_batch
>       is_training=True)
>     File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/gen_cudnn_rnn_ops.py", line 116, in cudnn_rnn
>       is_training=is_training, name=name)
>     File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/op_def_library.py", line 787, in _apply_op_helper
>       op_def=op_def)
>     File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/util/deprecation.py", line 488, in new_func
>       return func(*args, **kwargs)
>     File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 3274, in create_op
>       op_def=op_def)
>     File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 1770, in **init**
>       self._traceback = tf_stack.extract_stack()

InvalidArgumentError (see above for traceback): No OpKernel was registered to support Op 'CudnnRNN' with these attrs.  Registered devices: [CPU], Registered kernels:

```
 [[node cu_dnnlstm/CudnnRNN (defined at <ipython-input-15-580eb6f63222>:3)  = CudnnRNN[T=DT_FLOAT, direction="unidirectional", dropout=0, input_mode="linear_input", is_training=true, rnn_mode="lstm", seed=0, seed2=0](cu_dnnlstm/transpose, cu_dnnlstm/ExpandDims, cu_dnnlstm/ExpandDims_1, cu_dnnlstm/concat)]]
```

Comment: Looking at the error, it seems it is trying to run with the GPU which you have not configured to run DL models.

Answer (score 1):

You are running a CuDNN-based layer (most likely CuDNNLSTM) on the CPU, which won't work because the CuDNN implementation is only available for NVIDIA GPUs with CUDA.

Solution would be to replae the CuDNNLSTM layer with a normal LSTM layer.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that your Mac does have a Nvidia GPU? Besides, it supports CuDNN?

Comment: He's definitely trying to run a GPU-configured model on a probably non nvidia graphics card.